# After mounting / instead of /system now phone not booting system

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, twrp, fastboot

I used `mount -o rw,remount,rw /` command instead of `mount -o rw,remount,rw /system` now system not booting, please help. Every time restart and boot into fastboot but now system. TWRP working.

Infinix hot 8 android 10
i was trying to copy certificate file to ssytem/etc/security/cacerts so run remount command.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=ext4+dedup